# How can I limit a wordpress query to include only 1 post that share a tag or image?

Tags: wordpress, tags, related-posts

I've written a small script to retrieve and display 4 random posts from the same category as the main post. The problem is 6 posts in this category (tagged Q&A) have the same image. So if the script displays two or three Q&A posts, it displays the same image 2-3 times.

Is it possible to limit the query to retrieve 4 posts from a category, but only include 1 of the posts that share the Q&A tag and image?

This is the function I'm currently using:

```
function wcr_related_posts($args) {
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category(); 

    // default args
    $common_args = array(
        'numberposts'   => 4,
        'orderby'          => 'rand',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'),
        'post_type'        => "post",
        'post_status'      => "publish",
        'post__not_in'     => array($post->ID)
    );

    $cat_search_args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => $category[0]->name
            )
        ));
    $feature_posts_args = array(
        'post__in' => array( 705, 1883, 4897, 3967, 3766, 3585, 2698, 2412, 2203, 2575, 282, 4040)

                );

    if ( in_array($category[0]->name, array('Erotic Hypnosis', 'Dominance and Submission', 'Sexual Health'))&& is_page()!== true){
            $args = wp_parse_args($cat_search_args, $common_args);
        }else {
            $args = wp_parse_args($feature_posts_args, $common_args);
        }

    //  use for diagnostics only
    //  print_r($args); 

    // query
    $related_posts = get_posts($args);

    // get template
    include_once( __DIR__ . '/relatedposts-template.php');

    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! It might be useful to include the script you've written to pull these posts, so the community can provide you with more specific guidance based on your code. In addition, it would definitely be useful to include any efforts you've explored trying to solve this, and why they didn't address the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the post to include my code.